# CSS navigation bar

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I am playing around with CSS and so far I'am trying to make a website. I making a navigation bar and it's going down so it's horizontal. I need it to go across and I also need like 1 grey line to separate the tabs out. This is what I got so far.

HTML:

```
<div class="horizontal">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="Register.html">Register</a></li>
<li><a href="Rules.html">Rules</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.horizontal
{
width:809px;
height:63px;
position:relative;
top: -1046px;
left: 104px;
}
div.horizontal ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
div.horizontal li
{
float:left;
}
div.horizontal a
{
display:block;
width:809px;
}
div.horizontal a:link,div.horizontal a:visited
{
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#000000;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
div.horizontal a:hover,div.horizontal a:active
{
background-color:#999999;
}
```

So again this goes downwards , i need it to go to the side and just have like a single line which separate every tab out.

Comment: Is this correct: top: -1046px; ?

Comment: on my website ye i got some crazy things going around but atm just trying to figure out this problem

Answer (score 1):

```
div.horizontal
{
width:809px;
height:63px;
position:relative;
left: 104px;
}
div.horizontal ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
div.horizontal li
{
display: inline-block;
    margin-left:5px;
}
div.horizontal a
{
display:block;
width:809px;
}
div.horizontal a:link,div.horizontal a:visited
{
font-weight:bold;
display: inline;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#000000;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
div.horizontal a:hover,div.horizontal a:active
{
background-color:#999999;
}
```

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/EpPSv/10/

Comment: That has done nothing i changed it in my code but not working

Comment: @MadMan can you recreate your issue in jsFiddle then? or send your website?

Comment: @MadMan see my edit- remove `text-align: center` from `div.horizontal a:link, div.horizontal a:visited` and it works :). You need to also remove the `top: -1000px` too.

Comment: @MadMan Please select the answer if this is what you were looking for.